# Filter a list with Symfony2 and the EasyAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm using this bundle to get a fast and viable administration. Everything is fine but I'm not able to do this.

When the user is logged in and goes to the "User List" I need to filter the other users he can see (I've got a User-Department relationship), so he only sees the users in his/her department.

Is there a way to do that without modifying the controllers? I already did it modifying them but I lost the order functionalities of the list.

Comment: the best way is modify controller or service that filter entity. please paste your code, so its easy to solve your problem.